# what does error reporting level mean?

Tags: php, error-reporting

As shown in the php documentation for error reporting. What does the term error reporting level mean in layman terms?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

I know how to use the error_reporting() function. But technical terms are gibberish to me.

Comment: **Advice:** Always set it to `-1` when you are working on your code, and fix any errors, warnings and notices you get. `error_reporting(-1);`.

Comment: **Advice:** Don't set it to `-1`, instsead set it to `E_ALL`. `-1` is semantically meaningless and isn't guaranteed to work on every system. ;-)

Comment: @kba Why wouldn't it work on some systems? It is just a way of turning on all the bits on; if that is not guaranteed to work then surely the system must be broken.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen First of all, it's not in the documentation to use `-1`, so arguably it's undefined behaviour—it could break in a future version whereas `E_ALL` won't. `-1` works on two's complement system, becuase -1 is the same as setting all bits on, which conveniently is higher than `E_ALL`'s value (32767). This is only the case on two's complement systems; it wouldn't work on a Ones' complement system. Is it unlikely that OP will be using Ones' complement? Sure, but it could break and there is no reason to _not_ follow the suggested `E_ALL` from the documentation.

Comment: @kba Touché. You are right. I did learn about compliments in a CS class but I guess it did not stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It determines what kind of messages are shown.

If `error_reporting` is set to 0, no errors or warnings are shown at all.

If you set it to show `E_NOTICE`, you will see notices such as:

> Undefined variable: var in ...

If `E_DEPRECATED` is enabled, you'll see messages such as:

> Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in ...

And so forth. The different flags (`E_ERROR`, `E_WARNING`, `E_PARSE`) present different levels of severity.

Generally, it's recommended to enable all messages in developing environments, but not show anything in production.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the minimum severity that an error has to be before PHP reports it (by printing a message, for example). There are different types of errors, from fatal (something happened and the script cannot go on) to warnings (potentially unsafe code) to deprecation warnings (code that works but won't work in the future) or general notices (something that's usually harmless but could cause an error).

In production, you want to disable them for security reasons (`error_reporting(0)`), but during development it's a good idea to leave them on `E_ALL` for debugging and to improve/future-proof your code.

Check out the [list of error reporting constants](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). It's roughly arranged most severe to least severe and clearly explains each level.

Answer (score -1):

In fact there are only 2 interesting error_reporting levels in most cases: `0` and `E_ALL` (assuming you use PHP 5.4+)

`0` - means that no errors are displayed at all - you should use this level on production (you don't want to show any errors to users or attackers)

`E_ALL` - when you develop your site you should display all errors/warnings/notices and so on to simply remove them

You set error reporting level in PHP using

```
ini_set('display_errors,'1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

when you want to display errors

and if you want to hide all errors you should use:

```
ini_set('display_errors,'0');
error_reporting(0);
```

You should of course read more about error_levels because messages give you info what's wrong in your code. For example if in your message you have something about deprecated it means that method you use is no longer recommended in this PHP version and you should consider use other method because in future PHP version the method you use could be removed.